# After including jquery plugin countdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a content editor webpart in sharepoint with the following code, However the countdown is not working.
What I noticed is that this site is using an old version of jquery 1.6.3, I wonder if that might be the cause or not.

```
<script src="/Style%20Library/countdown/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/countdown/jquery.countdown.css" />

<script class="ms-rteForeColor-3" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var austDay = new Date(2013, 7 - 1, 27);
        $('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    });
</script>

<div id="countdownBox">
    <h3 class="ms-rteElement-H3 ms-rteForeColor-3">Countdown to go-live</h3>
    <span class="countdown" id="countdown"></span>
</div>
```

**Update 1**

Error in firefox console. the error is flooded too many times on the console

Timestamp: 10/07/2013 08:13:21
Warning: Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: `https://xx/Communities/xx/Pages/project-xx.aspx`
Line: 0
Source Code:
alpha(opacity=99.00000000000007)

this is the generated html, I wonder if the css has to be in the head?

```
<DIV id=WebPartWPQ7 class="ms-WPBody noindex" allowDelete="false" width="100%" HasPers="false" WebPartID="c1b5cf92-534f-4d23-8cd0-8c0fbe8f541b">
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/Style%20Library/countdown/jquery.countdown.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style%20Library/countdown/jquery.countdown.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var austDay = new Date(2013, 7 - 1, 27);
    $('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    });</SCRIPT>

<DIV id=countdownBox>
<H3 class="ms-rteElement-H3 ms-rteForeColor-3">Countdown to go-live</H3><SPAN id=countdown class=countdown></SPAN></DIV></DIV>
```

Comment: check out the error in console  in firefox developer addon

Comment: @Luis Can you show us a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Fnsgk/2/

Comment: The script tags are not allowed in the javascript box: http://jsfiddle.net/Fnsgk/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsFiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Fnsgk/3

However you should add a closing script tag:

```
<script src="/Style%20Library/countdown/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```